# Can Panels just be uninstalled if you want to switch themes?

Tags: 7, panels, theming

I used panels + panels everywhere with precision theme to build a website.

I now rather want to use Zen theme with basic blocks.

I wish to keep the content types with their fields.

If I uninstall panels will all instances of it be removed from the site?
Or should I rather just rebuild the site from a new clean installation?

Comment: Only your custom theme was using panels?

Comment: Yes, The site is also really basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, uninstalling removes everything created by the module, its setting and its database tables.

But for what you are after, you don't even need to uninstall them, not even disabling to be honest, just don't use panels tools in your new theme.

Considering that, I would delay the idea of removing them and the old theme to after the new one is ready.
Just because of "how i did it in the other theme?" kind of questions